# Create different functions from loop in Python

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to build a tkinter GUI, and I'm having a Python programming logic issue. My problem is the following: I'm creating a bunch of objects in the following way:

```py
class Aplication:
    def createObjects(self):
        objects = []
        for i in range(10):
            obj = Object(command = lambda: self.myFunction(i))
            objects.append(obj)

    def myFunction(self, i):
        print(i)
```

And when executing each object's command I expected the result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

I simplified my code so that anyone who knows Python logic can help me.
Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This slightly modified version works as you expect.

It is essentially the variable scope problem.
In your implementation, the function looks for `i` in the runtime, when `i` has already been updated to 9.
If you want to keep the "current" value of `i`, you need to define a function with the current `i` like below.

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command
        
class Application:
    def createObjects(self):
        objects = []
        for i in range(10):
            obj = Object(command = self.myFunction(i))
            objects.append(obj)
        return objects
    
    def myFunction(self, i):
        return lambda: print(i)

a = Application()
os = a.createObjects()
for o in os:
    o.command()
```